# MapKit: Update radius property of MKCircle overlay without flickering

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I have a *MKMapView* (self.mapView) to which I add a *MKCircle* overlay (self.radiusOverlay) with a specific radius (self.location.radius).

Right below the *MKMapView* there is a *UISlider* (self.radiusSlider) which changes the overlay's radius on *Value Changed*:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.radiusOverlay = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.location.latitude floatValue], [self.location.longitude floatValue]) radius:[self.location.radius floatValue]];

    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.radiusOverlay];

    self.radiusSlider.value = [self.location.radius floatValue];
}
```

This is the method which does the radius-updating stuff:

```
- (IBAction)updateLocationRadius:(UISlider *)sender {

    [self.mapView removeOverlay:self.radiusOverlay];

    self.location.radius = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value];

    self.radiusOverlay = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.location.latitude floatValue], [self.location.longitude floatValue]) radius:[self.location.radius floatValue]];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.radiusOverlay];
}
```

This works fine, but it's not looking good: By removing and re-adding *self.radiusOverlay* I cause the overlay to flicker.

What can I do to avoid this flickering?

Comment: Try the suggestion in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876035/mkoverlay-not-resizing-smoothly).  Also see the last comment (May 8 at 19:28) on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759317/moving-mkcircle-in-mkmapview) for another alternative (but more complex).  For some more details related to the custom overlay view approach, see [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529217/is-there-away-to-add-text-using-paths-drawing).